# AngularJS 2-way binding in partial templates & refresh woes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have a partial template loaded outside of my `ng-view`, with it's own controller. It looks like this.

**Base template**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
   ...
   <div ng-include src="'myPartial.html'"></div>
   ...
   <div ng-view></div>
   ...
   <!-- script files go here -->
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="myPartialController.js"></script>
   <script src="myApp.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Main app script (`myApp.js`)**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myPartialController', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    .when('/myUrl', {
            templateUrl: 'myPartial.html',
            controller:'myPartialController',
            reloadOnSearch: true
        })
});
```

**Partial template (`myPartial.html`)**

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="myPartialController">
    {{myVariable}}
</div>
```

Now, inside the controller, I am reading a value from sessionStorage, doing a bunch of parsing, data manipulation and so on, and then finally setting the result to a `$scope` array variable.

**Partial controller (`myPartialController.js`)**

```
angular.module('myPartialController', [])

.controller('myPartialController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', function($scope, $rootScope, $window) {
    // some parsing, data manipulation, what have you's
    // and finally set the result array to myVariable.
    $scope.myVariable = myVariable;
}]);
```

Now when the partial is loaded, it shows just an empty array (`[]`). When I refresh the page, the correct array is displayed.

Essentially, 2-way binding isn't working. What am I missing?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code, maybe your info isn't being saved into sessionStorage at the right time. Shows up there after you refresh or something...

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS That was my original doubt too. However, isn't 2-way binding supposed to update the variable on the template whenever it changes?

Comment: Can you show where you are loading your JS? Also, what is myVariable value when the DOM is rendered?

Comment: Why do you use `ng-include src="'myPartial.html'"` and then also define the main route "/" to render this partial too? Same thing goes for the controller associated w/the partial. As shown, you're instantiating two controllers (and perhaps 2 HTML templates). Am I missing something?

Comment: I had to redact a lot of my code, and I left that in. My bad. It is actually a different URL. I tried to remove the controller instantiation in the `$routeProvider`, but that didn't help or affect my original problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `myVariable` gets the value after an async/callback function and that it indeed has the expected value at that point, Angular is not aware of the change until it reaches the next scope digest cycle.

However, you can force one by doing `$scope.$apply()` or wrapping the assignment line inside `$timeout` callback.

---

See what I mean in this simple example:

```js
angular.module('a', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.valA = $scope.valB = 'not set yet';

    setTimeout(function() { // simulated async call
      $scope.valA = 'first one set';
      $scope.$apply();
      $scope.valB = 'second one set'; // this one will wait another cycle
    }, 500)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="a" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <p>{{valA}}</p>
  <p>{{valB}}</p>
  <p><button ng-click="">Force Digest</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright so `setTimeout()` seems to do the trick. I have a small related problem, and hope you wouldn't mind helping out with. I do this thing right after a user logs in, and the value of `myValue` is different for each user. The problem now is, when a user A logs in and logs out, and then user B logs in, I still see `myValue` of user A; I can see `myValue` of user B only on a page reload. Is this a related issue?

Comment: Sounds like the same thing to me. What happens when you force a digest cycle on every login/logout call?

Comment: Hmmm, without seeing the whole thing I can't help you much. However, I can suggest you try adding a button that will force the digest (a blank `ng-click` attribute will work), so you can do it whenever you want. That will help you determine whether the issue is with the scope or something else (like sessionStorage). See my updated example.